# Disable fading in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

Is there a possibility to disable gray fade in effect of UISearchBar when activated. 
I tryed the following in viewDidLoad and nothing worked:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView.frame = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can code the desired behavior in your `- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar` function

You can refer to this [helpful tutorial](http://jduff.github.com/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/) and just remove the following part that is responsible for the fading effect

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0.6;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```